# How to preserve the newline character in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, html-encode

I have a **databound** asp.net webform grid. In the one column I have a **multiline** comment field.

I call a custom edit form on which the comment field is passed as a **parameter** on the url. I build the url up and the part which contains the comment field is built using `<%# Eval("FILE_COMMENT") %>`  . But the comment field **loses** its **newline character**.

How can I preserve it?

Comment: `<pre>` tag is one way - now your turn to come up with something